# Php While loop only displaying one record

Tags: php

I am trying to go through each record in my db and update the row. It works, but only one at a time.

```
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('webinar', $con);       
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE mon=0 AND 1hour=0 AND 10min=0 AND wed=0 AND complete=0");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['email'];
            $res = "UPDATE register SET mon=1 WHERE id=".$row['id']."";
            $result = mysql_query($res);
        }
```

Comment: Sidenote: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Please use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. Referencing: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run

```
UPDATE register SET mon=1 WHERE mon=0 AND 1hour=0 AND 10min=0 AND wed=0 AND complete=0
```

Example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, email FROM register WHERE mon=0 AND 1hour=0 AND 10min=0 AND wed=0 AND complete=0");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['email'];
}

 // now update!
 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE register SET mon=1 WHERE mon=0 AND 1hour=0 AND 10min=0 AND wed=0 AND complete=0");
```

Comment: But then I cannot echo the email. I need to actually mail each person, but I put echo in for now until I get this sorted out

Comment: And you do... what was your question? Maybe I misunderstood. Better clarify your question.

Comment: Ohhh I see. I didn't think to update them all at once. thanks!